# An flawed proof about quantifiers

Tags: logic, quantifiers

Consider a propositional function $P(a)$ with a definite truth value for elements from $D$.

I am going to show that $\forall x \in D (P(x)) \equiv \exists x \in D (P(x))$

(obviously this is not true, but I would like to find the specific flaw in my reasoning)

I will be using these 4 logical equivalences:

Let $c$ be an arbitrary element from $D$.

A. $P(c) \equiv \forall x \in D (P(x))$

B. $P(c) \equiv \neg (\neg P(c))$

C. $\neg P(c) \equiv \forall x \in D (\neg P(x))$

D. $\neg (\forall x \in D (\neg P(x))) \equiv \exists x \in D (P(x))$

Proof: $\forall x \in D (P(x)) \equiv P(c) \equiv \neg (\neg P(c)) \equiv \neg (\forall x \in D (\neg P(x))) \equiv \exists x \in D (P(x))$

What have I done wrong here to reach this incorrect conclusion? Specifically, what rules of propositional logic have I violated?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You're misusing universal generalization.

Comment: A and C together are wrong: $c$ cannot be both P and not-P at the same time.

Comment: And from $\lnot \lnot P(c)$ you can derive $\forall x \lnot \lnot P(x)$ and not  $\lnot \forall x \lnot P(x)$

Comment: Thank you for your time. My issue is that if one proposition is embedded inside another, and you have a logically equivalent inner proposition, then you should be able to replace the inner proposition. Specifically, you should be able to replace $\neg P(c)$ with $\forall x \in D(\neg P(x))$ because they are logically equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equivalences such as between $P(c)$ holding for arbitrary $c$ and $\forall x\,P(x)$ are not logical equivalences $P(c)\leftrightarrow \forall x\,P(x)$ that, like equality, would allow us to swap these two anywhere when they appear nested deeply in a complex formula. Rather, they are (in this case, bidirectional) rules of inference that are per se applicable only at "top level".

In other words, we have
$$ P(c)\vdash \forall x\,P(x)$$and $$\forall x\,P(x)\vdash P(c), $$
but in general not
$$ f(P(c))\vdash f(\forall x\,P(x))$$
and not$$ f(\forall x\,P(x))\vdash f(P(c)).$$
In particular, we do **not** have
$$ \neg\forall x\, P(x)\vdash \neg P(c)$$
(though $$ \neg P(c)\vdash \neg\forall x\, P(x)$$
happens to be correct, but not by just a single inference step)

Comment: Thank you for your time. My problem is that if $p \implies q$ and $q \implies p$, then $p \equiv q$. The fact that this exception exists must suggest either a problem with the rules, or that $P(c)$ and $\forall x P(x)$ are not propositions. I did not find any mention of a rule to deal with this exception in my discrete math textbook (Discrete Mathematics and its Applications - Rosen).

Comment: Is there any special name for this logical equivalence that is only applicable on the "top level"? If you know of any outside material on this, I would love to read it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your A. and C. are incorrect; the equivalence $P(c) \equiv \forall x P(x)$ does not hold (and neither with a negation). We have $\forall x P(x) \vDash P(c)$, but $P(c) \nvDash \forall x P(x)$.

$\forall x P(x) \vDash P(c)$ is an application of the rule of universal instantiation: $\forall x P(x) \vDash P(x)[x/t]$, for an arbitrary term $t$. If $P$ holds of all objects, then it holds of each instance of individuals.

There is no rule that would allow one to infer $P(c) \vDash \forall x P(x)$: From $P$ holding of one concrete object $c$ we can not infer that it holds for all objects.
There is the rule of universal generalization, but that works differently: It requires that 1. the term in the premise be a variable $y$, not a constant $c$, and that 2. the variable be arbitrary, in the sense that $P(y)$ does not depend on any open assumptions about $y$.
In $P(c)$, $c$ is not an arbitrary object, but rather $P(c)$ still depends on an open assumption, namely the assumption $P(c)$ itself, which is not proven.

You do have $\forall x P(x) \vDash P(c) \vDash \exists x P(x)$, but the reverse direction does not hold: Neither can you infer from the truth of $P$ for one particular object $c$ that $P$ holds of all objects.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I was wondering if you could elaborate on why my $c$ is not an arbitrary element. I made sure to clarify that $c$ was an arbitrary element from $D$.

Comment: $c$ is not arbitrary because we imposed conditions on it: Namely we assumed that $P$ holds of $c$ -- assumptions depend on themselves! We may infer $\forall x P(x)$ from $P(y)$ only if we have a proof $\Gamma \vdash P(y)$ where $y$ does not occur free in $\Gamma$ -- bc. the assumptions about $y$ are the additional conditions which make the object non-arbitrary. If at the current stage of your proof you just have $P(y)$ as an assumption, then the situation is $P(y) \vdash P(y)$, with $y$ free in the assump. $P(y)$, and the object is no longer arbitrary, bc. it depends on the cond. that $P(y)$.